# Problems with Transfer Service from Google Ads to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, transfer

I am having a problem with a data transfer from Google Ads. When I schedule the backfill I get the following error for some dates:

> Invalid value: Load configuration must specify at least one source URI

When I check the log inside of the details of execution I get the following message:

> Failed to start job for table p_ClickStats_5419416216$20201117 with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid value: Load configuration must specify at least one source URI

The weird part is that this happens for random dates which I had transfered before in a previous transfer. Did anyone have a problem similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with the same error. I was using a free trial account. I shared my project under another account that was an upgraded account with billing set-up (but still with the promotional credits). So far, I have not had the same issue. Try to upgrade your account to one where you set up billing and try the data transfer again. Don't use the purely free trial account. You can share the project to the other account and set it up there, the data transfer. Backfilling for me has also worked and looks like no more duplicate runs either. Maybe free account trial is a limited version.